# Split test sentences to fit BERT model max length in NER. Better ways to do it?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I have fine-tuned a BERT model for name entity recognition. Now, I am trying to make inference over some test sentences (from which I have a gold standard). I am facing the problem described [here](https://github.com/kamalkraj/BERT-NER/issues/77) and [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1791).

*"Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this BERT model (XXX > 512). Running this sequence through BERT will result in indexing errors"*

My question is, what is the best approach to handle this in NER task? (Other questions related to this issue are oriented to question answering/sentence classification)

Is it okay to split each test sentence (assuming some context loss), into n fragments to ensure n<MAX_LEN, make the predictions and the re-assemble the fragments into the original sentences?

What is the best approach to do the "cut" into the fragments?, is there any accepted rule or publication that discuss this?

Training longformers is not possible

Thank you